# BackupPC files on NFS - web interface not working

Tags: nfs, timeout, backuppc

if BackupPC files from dir /var/lib/BackupPC is moved to NFS mount, web interface not working. I see an only home page, but when I want to go to host config or to summary webpage timeouts (504 Gateway Timeout).

In BackupPC logs isn't anything relevant. In httpd error log are these lines:

```
[Wed Jun 07 14:39:04.655260 2017] [cgi:warn] [pid 1078] [client 83.208.46.101:53404] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /usr/share/BackupPC/sbin/BackupPC_Admin, referer: http://10.0.0.15:8081/backuppc?action=summary
[Wed Jun 07 14:39:04.655326 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 1078] [client 83.208.46.101:53404] Script timed out before returning headers: BackupPC_Admin, referer: http://10.0.0.15:8081/backuppc?action=summary
```

If I switched configuration back (/etc/BackupPC/config.pl, variable $Conf{TopDir}), all works fine.

I use CentOS Linux 7 x64 and BackupPC-3.3.1-5.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the old version of NFS share and hardlinks which BackupPC ver. 3 use. I updated to version 4.